# What are the "poles" of a signal (after it's reflected perhaps)

Tags: resonance, dielectric

I desire to learn about "estimating the poles of a resonant signal", specifically the complex natural resonance of objects.

However, I don't know what "poles" are. What would you suggest I look up for better resources? :)

Comment: poles are where the system amplitude can head toward infinity, because of a denominator heading toward zero. Hence the amplitude is a POST or POLE sticking up out of the ground.

Comment: [Intuition for resonant, natural, and oscillatory frequencies of RLC circuits?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/233654/intuition-for-resonant-natural-and-oscillatory-frequencies-of-rlc-circuits?rq=1)

Comment: [What are some insights from looking at Bode plots](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/160140/what-are-some-insights-from-looking-at-bode-plots)

Comment: [What is the difference between frequency response and transfer function?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275362/what-is-the-difference-between-frequency-response-and-transfer-function)

Comment: [Meaning of Sigma in Laplace transform](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/316918/meaning-of-sigma-in-laplace-transform)

Comment: There is no such a thing as a "pole of a signal". It's not the signal that can have a pole but the **system**.

Comment: maybe the sequence of Youtube videos ["The Root Locus Method"](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUMWjy5jgHK3-ca6GP6PL0AgcNGHqn33f) (by Brian Douglas) is helpful

Comment: Comment to the first comment: "System amplitude" should mean: The value (not the amplitude) of the complex transfer function expressed using the complex frequency variable s=sigma+j*omega.

Comment: The quotation marks indicate that you have read 'poles of a resonant signal' somewhere. Please give us that reference. Perhaps 'signal' should be 'system'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, signals don't have "poles", systems do.

The transfer function of a system in many cases can be expressed as a ratio of two polynomials.

$$G(s) = \frac{A_ms^m + A_{m-1}s^{m-1} + ... + A_1s + A_0}{B_ns^n + B_{n-1}s^{n-1} + ... + B_1s + B_0}$$

There are values of \$s\$ for which the upper polynomial evaluates to zero. When that happens, the value of \$G(s)\$ must be zero, regardless of the value of the lower polynomial. These values of \$s\$ — the roots of that polynomial — are referred to as "zeros" of the transfer function.

Similarly, there are values of \$s\$ for which the lower polynomial evaluates to zero. When that happens, the value of \$G(s)\$ goes to infinity, regardless of the value of the upper polynomial. These values of \$s\$ — the roots of that polynomial — are referred to as "poles" of the transfer function.

We sometimes imagine the response of the system — the values of \$G(s)\$ — as a "rubber sheet" that is stretched over the \$s\$ plane. The "zeros" of the transfer function are the places where that sheet is stuck to the \$s\$ plane, and the "poles" are frequencies where the sheet is pushed up by an infinitely tall pole, which is where the term comes from. In between, the sheet finds intermediate values that are determined mostly by the poles and zeros that are nearest to it.

Here's an example of such a visualization:

[image: pole-zero plot]

[Source](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepZPK.html)